# PyGame, I want to be able to delay some code without delaying the whole program

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am creating a game using PyGame.

I want to make my character look like it is running all the time. To do this I would have to swtich between the two sprites. However doing this normally results in the image changing too quickly and if i add

```
time.sleep(1)
```

It pauses the whole program for that time. When it does this is does not allow me to input anything during that pause time.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()


white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,155,0)


display_width = 500
display_height = 500



gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))



pygame.display.set_caption("Sword")
gameDisplay.fill(white)

pygame.display.update()

sUp = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/michael/Google Drive/PyGame/Images/image4.png")
sUp = pygame.transform.scale(sUp, (500,500))
sUp1 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/michael/Google Drive/PyGame/Images/image5.png")
sUp1 = pygame.transform.scale(sUp1, (500,500))
sDown = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/michael/Google Drive/PyGame/Images/image6.png")
sDown = pygame.transform.scale(sDown, (500,500))   


def SUP(x=0, y=0):
    gameDisplay.blit(sUp, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()


def SDOWN(x=0, y=0):
    gameDisplay.blit(sDown, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()

def running(x=0, y=0):
    gameDisplay.blit(sUp, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(1)

    gameDisplay.blit(sUp1, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(1)

def gameLoop():
    game = True

    while game == True:
        running()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print event

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    SDOWN()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    SUP()

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

gameLoop()
```

This is my code. If there are any better ways to do this please let me know.

Thanks

I have updated it using your suggestions but it returns the error I mentioned in the comment. Ive checked the code and I'm pretty sure its all correct.

```
frames = [sUp, sUp1] # Defined at the top of the code to define the frames 
frameid = 0 # The current frame
lastframe = None


def SUP(x=0, y=0):
    gameDisplay.blit(sUp, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()


def SDOWN(x=0, y=0):
    gameDisplay.blit(sDown, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()

def running(x=0, y=0):
    global frameid
    gameDisplay.blit(frames[frameid], (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    frameid = 1 if frameid == 0 else 0

def gameLoop():
    game = True
    lastframe = time.time()
    while game == True:
        if time.time() - lastframe() > 0.25: # Ensure we only update animation every 1/4 second
           running()
           lastframe = time.time()

        time = datetime.now()
        print time
        running()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print event

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    SDOWN()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    SUP()

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

    time.sleep(0.1)  # Run the game at 10 loops per second.
gameLoop()
```

Comment: what you need to do, rather than sleep is use the clock to record the time that you display the sprite, and then each time round the loop, check the clock again, and work out how much to sleep (to get the right number of frames per second, and also whether the change sprites for the animation - so the two are running at different speeds

Comment: How can I record the time and what type of loop should I use? I'm quite new to this so I don't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: use `datetime.now()` to record the current time. You already have a while loop - you don't need anything else. Change your `running` method so it records which frame is currently displayed, and display the next one when called - don't try to do all the frames in one call.The short sleep and test on the elapsed time all go in the while loop

Comment: sorry but I'm really confused, first of all it says datetime.now(): module now() unavailable. Also by record do you mean store it in a variable? And how do I call a frame.

Comment: see my answer - it might help - or confuse even more

Answer (score 1):

Parts of my comments ....

At the top of the module :

```
frames = [sup, sup1] # Defined at the top of the code to define the frames 
frameid = 0 # The current frame
lastframe = None
```

Change running function to :

```
def running(x=0, y=0):
    global frameid
    gameDisplay.blit(frames[frameid], (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    frameid = 1 if frameid == 0 else 0
```

in the gameloop function :

```
 lastframe = time.time()
 while game == True:
 if time.time() - lastframe > 0.25: # Ensure we only update animation every 1/4 second
       running()
       lastframe = time.time()
```

At the end of the loop :

```
 time.sleep(0.1)  # Run the game at 10 loops per second.
```

None of this is tested.

Comment: Thanks for this, but it returns time is referenced before it is assigned

Comment: so you have put things in the wrong order - or forgotten something - think about what the error means

Comment: I edited my question to include the code I have now which still returns that error and by looking at it I can't see why

Comment: I fixed the error by removeing some of the old code which was affecting it. Now it results in a error:
if time.time() - lastframe() > 0.25: # Ensure we only update animation every 1/4 second
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable